# mysqli_query giving me unsolvable message

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to make a basic song info page, and my only problem is the SQL. I keep getting this message:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /var/www/tts/recommend-action.php on line 33

Here is my code:

```php
<?php

session_start();

ini_set("display_errors",true);

ob_start();

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "root";
$pass = "[MYPASSWORD]";
$db = "[MYDATABASE]";
$tb = "recommendation";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die("Failed to connect.");

$song = $_POST['song'];
$album = $_POST['album'];
$artist = $_POST['artist'];
$linkitunes = $_POST['linkitunes'];
$artwork = $_POST['albumPic'];

$song = stripslashes($song);
$album = stripslashes($album);
$artist = stripslashes($artist);
$link = stripslashes($linkitunes);
$artwork = stripslashes($artwork);

print "<br /><br /><b>User ID: </b>" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "<br /><b>Song: </b>$song<br /><b>Album: </b>$album<br /><b>Artist: </b>$artist<br /><br />";

$sql = "INSERT INTO recommendation (user_id, artist, song, album, artwork, linkitunes) VALUES (" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ", $artist, $song, $album, $artwork, $linkitunes);";

$postrec = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if ($postrec == true) {
    print "sucess";
}
else {
    print "<br /><br />failed";
}

ob_flush();

?>
```

I cannot find a solution. Help is very greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know for a fact that all the connections are valid. No problem there.

Comment: Besides the answer below, you're more than likely are passing strings in your values. `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()` would have thrown an error.

Comment: Since you are pulling in your answers from $_POST, it could just be easier to use a prepared statement. Would protect you from most damaging effects of the values you're trying to insert. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php @CameronMontesano

Comment: What do you mean passing strings in my values?

Comment: Take it up with the answer below. No sense for me putting in one now, not a "partial" answer anyway. I'll get downvoted for it. No thanks. Read this too http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php which may very well pop up some new errors on top of what you're receiving now. I've never heard of an artist called `12345`. UB 40, but that contains a string ;-)

Comment: **Building SQL statements with outside variables makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.** Also, any input data with single quotes in it, like "O'Malley", will blow up your query. Learn about parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) has many detailed examples. See also http://bobby-tables.com/php for alternatives & explanation of the danger.

Comment: I now get this message:

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: link in /var/www/tts/recommend-action.php on line 33 Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in /var/www/tts/recommend-action.php on line 33

Comment: You said you changed the variable name of the string. Did you change the name of your `mysqli_connect` variable? `$link = mysqli_connect(...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You connect fine and `$link` is good:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die("Failed to connect.");
```

But then later redefine as a string:

```
$link = stripslashes($linkitunes);
```

And then you try and use the string:

```
$postrec = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

Comment: Changed it back, but I now get this message:

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: link in /var/www/tts/recommend-action.php on line 33 Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in /var/www/tts/recommend-action.php on line 33

Comment: @CameronMontesano [Because you didn't read this...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200003/mysqli-query-giving-me-unsolvable-message#comment44766376_28200003) well, partially anyway.

Comment: @CameronMontesano What do you mean by "changed it back"? What did you change?

Comment: @showdev I changed the link string name. The link no longer interferes.